# Add time picker only to the custom collection data field of spfx using react ts framework

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx

I am unable to add the time picker to the custom collection data in SPFx. Please provide me a code that I can use for my project. Just the part from custom collection date

I am not able to bind the value that is selected from the timepicker